# Using Recursive CTE on ORACLE to create a multicolumn filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, vba

I am currently using a VBA function to loop over an Oracle result set to eliminate duplicates on multiple columns/fields (i.e. only distinct values in each column) For example:

My result set is ordered by RECORD_ID, and I want to eliminate FIELD_1 and FIELD_2 duplication:

```
RECORD_ID   FIELD_1     FIELD_D
1           A           i
2           A           j
3           B           i
4           B           k
5           C           j
6           C           k
7           D           k
```

So my program creates a new table (say FINAL_TABLE) and evaluates every line in the original sql resultset (say TABLE_1):

**IF** the current value of TALBE_1.FIELD_1 **IS NOT** in FINAL_TABLE.FIELD_1 **AND** the current value of TALBE_1.FIELD_2 **IS NOT** in FINAL_TABLE.FIELD_2 **THEN** insert record/row into FINAL_TABLE

This results in

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
1           A           i
4           B           k
5           C           j
```

Where there is only unique values on both columns 2 and 3.

I have tried looking into a way of moving away from loops into SQL with the LAG and PATTERN MATCHING functions but cant figure it out. (cant think of a way to use distinct)

I have also looked at methods that create a table of possible combinations and then select from there but this is unfeasible since only a couple of thousand rows of data would make the number of combinations too large for most computers to handle.

Bottom line: **Can this logic be implemented through a recursive SQL query?**

Comment: I think you would have to implement this logic using recursive CTEs.  Are you using 11g?

Comment: Yes I am using 11g. Never dealt with CTEs, going to have a read. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, this processing requires a sequential pass through the data.  You might as well leave well enough along and keep the code in VB.  Although it can be done in the database, you will lose some of the advantages of database processing.

Comment: My issue really is that the data I get from the SQL query is about 4 million records, so its hard to execute in VB and certainly too time consuming when ran on the end-user PC. I wanted to offset this processing to the server for two reasons (capacity and time). So is this a dead end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the result set in a temporary table, then I think you can do this with `delete`:

```
delete from temp
    where exists (select 1
                  from temp t2
                  where t2.id < temp.id and (t2.col2 = temp.col2 or t2.col3 = temp.col3)
                 );
```

Comment: Ooo! Let me try, sounds simple yet efficient :D

Comment: I'm still pondering over why the `delete` seems so easy to express, yet I can't think of a way to do it in the other direction.  This may be an example of an interesting class of problem.

Comment: What is the t you are comparing against? t is not defined.

Comment: @user3460414 . . . That should just be the original table.  I'm not sure that this will really work in general.  Maybe it will solve your problem though.  This is a very subtle problem.

Comment: The solution doesnt work since it will look at ALL the rows in the resultset. I am looking at a Recursive WITH, but cant figure it out either!